# window.XMLHttpRequest is undefined in IE7/IE8

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

Value of window.XMLHttpRequest is Undefined when i run my application even in IE7 or IE8, Is there anything i have to enable in IE7 to make it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this:

```
if (!window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  window.XMLHttpRequest = function() {
    return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  };
}
```

I recommend looking at an AJAX library though, life is much easier in jQuery, ExtJS, MooTools, whatever you prefer.

Comment: window.XNLHttpRequest is undefined in my case if i use the code if(!window.XMLHttpRequest) would give me an error.

Comment: @Arvind - Did you try it?  It works fine: `!(undefined thing)` == true in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I enabled the native XMLHTTP support from internet options, after this the my code started working fine.

Comment: This is not the answer. The problem is in your application. If you want to support IE7/8/9, you can't ask all your users to change their IE settings to use your application. Well, you can, but that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/jed/993585/#comment-40084

```
var xhr = (function(){
    try{
        return new(this.XMLHttpRequest||ActiveXObject)('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    } catch(e) {};
}());
```