# Ajax script fails in IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8

The following script executes and works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox - but not in IE8. Unfortunately IE8 is one of my targeted browsers so this is a bit of a problem. Since I don't have a lot of experience with Ajax I'm not really sure where to begin looking either.

I've noted that IE reports an error on line 15 (marked with **) which doesn't really make sense as the if-else should stop it from even looking at that line.

```
function getNames(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    // Clear previous queries
    if(str.length == 0){
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
        // Due to the high number of possible hits we'll demand 3 chars
        // before we start querying.
    }else if(str.length < 3){
        return ;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{ // code for IE6, IE5
        **xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");**
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (){        
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
            // String from get_names.php is comma separated
            var arr = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
            // The UL list we want our names in
            var ul = document.getElementById("names");

            // Clear the list for each key in
            if(ul.hasChildNodes()){
                while(ul.childNodes.length >= 1){
                    ul.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
                }
            }
            // Step trough the String in Array form
            for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
                // :@ means that we've reached the end of applicable names.
                if (arr[i] != ":@") {
                    var li = document.createElement("li");
                    li.innerHTML = newListItem = arr[i];
                    // Inserts the current name into the list.
                    ul.insertBefore(li, ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "./ext/get_names.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Stock answer: Have you considered using a framework such as jQuery for this? They take care of all this cross-browser shennanigans for you.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but perhaps you should consider a js framework (jQuery/mootools/...). These work cross-platform, and save you the headache

Comment: Could you add logic in to test if the active x object is available ie: (if (window.ActiveXObject))

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the readyState and *then* check the status. This is a common error that is reported but ignored in most browsers. I'm not sure that this is the solution to your problem, but since you haven't provided the error message, it's hard to help you further.

```
if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   // Code ...
}
```

Comment: Why does the order matter? It shouldn't unless *reading* `readyState` causes a *side effect* on `status` ... which is just silly :-/ (Note that it is just a logical conjunction: `&&`.)

Comment: Because the attribute 'status' can only be accessed when the readState equals 4 (or 3). Accessing the variable, when the readyState is not one of these values, will in at least Chrome and Firefox throw an error.

Comment: Right, so why is `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200` different than `xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4` (in the post)? While I agree that it's a *more logical* layout, assuming there are no side-effects, `a && b` and `b && a` are logically equivalent.

Comment: That's correct, but it's the order of execution that's relevant. First the xmlhttp.readyState == 4 is evaluated, if it is false, the browser will return from the if statement, because no matter what the outcome of the xmlhttp.status == 200 is, the if-clause will return false. This is not about the boolean value returned, but about when the property is accessed.

Comment: Please see my previous comments: **assuming there are no side-effects, `a && b` and `b && a` are logically equivalent**. Given that fact, *why* is the order important in this case?

Comment: Well then please see my previous comment. It's a matter of browser execution. You are correct that they're logically equivalent, *but* it's not equivalent in browser execution context. If you write the clause with the xmlhttp.status == 200, first then *that* will be executed first and it'll cause an Error if the readyState isn't equal to 4. So yea, you could call the error a "side-effect" but it isn't really, and that's why the order is important.

Comment: An exception *is* a side-effect. See previous comment ;-) I was not aware it would throw an exception ^^

Comment: Hmm, I'll try. Regarding the error it only reads "Unspecified error at line 15" ...

Comment: Changing the order (state first, then status) did have some effect: IE now reports an error on line 38, "Invalid argument".

Line 38 is: ul.insertBefore(li, ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0]);

Comment: Instead of using the ul.getElementsByTagName('li')[0], you should use ul.firstChild, that might solve your problem. If not, then check the existence of the ul and the il variable with console.log.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the 'window.XMLHttpRequest'-check should be ok.

You could try taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3563477/1256868) answer. In that case, the problem was that native xmlhttprequest was disabled in the browser settings.