# IE8 Getting Object expected error - occurring on var keyword declaring XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

To start, I have never had this issue before, and I am baffled by this.  I have searched, but this 'Object expected' error refers to a lot of different things.  I am only getting this error in IE8, not in Chrome or Firefox, however I have not tried any previous or later versions of IE.

Here is the start of my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Company Acronym List</title>

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var ACRONYM_CSV_LIST = '/acronyms/acronyms.csv';
    var globalAcronymList = [];

    console.log ('Initiating script');

    function xmlGet ( url, callback ) {

        console.log ('Inside the Get method');

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200 ) {
                callback( xmlhttp.responseText );
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send(  );
    }

    function commit () {

        console.log('Commit started');

        var acronymSpan = document.getElementById('acronym-span');

        acronymSpan.style.color = '#eee';

        initLoadAcronymCsvList ();
    }

    function initLoadAcronymCsvList () {
        console.log ('Starting the XML Get');
        xmlGet( ACRONYM_CSV_LIST, acronymCsvListCallback );
    }
```

I am getting the 'Error: Object expected' message right at the `var xmlhttp = ...` line.  In fact, IE8 points right to the 'v' in the `var` keyword as being the error. *Why!?*

For sanity's sake, I even added some console tracing.  The `commit()` function is placed in the `<body onload="commit();">` tag, so when the page loads, I see the following console trace:

```
Initiating script
Commit started
Starting the XML Get
Inside the Get method
```

And then boom!  Just by using the `var` keyword I get an IE8 error.  I tried changing the name of the variable too ... and nothing!

I checked for semicolons and everything, and from the code snippet above, you should be able to see the code flow from where execution starts to where it fails.  I even broke the script out into its own separate file.  Is there a known issue I can refer to solve this?

Comment: Does replacing your var with this works? `var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")`

Comment: Yes it does work.  My bad for not picking up on that earlier.  For some reason I trusted IE8's debugging tools to point me to right where the error was occurring, rather than the start of the JavaScript statement causing the error.

Comment: I *think* IE8 does support native XMLHttpRequest, but it is not enabled by default so fallback to ActiveX is required.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter It probably depends on how your machine is configured...I have IE8 on my Windows XP VM and it supports XMLHttpRequest out of the box; I never changed the settings. But clearly you can't assume that it's enabled. The way to handle this is discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363212/window-xmlhttprequest-is-undefined-in-ie7-ie8, as MichaelPlautz pointed out.

Answer (score -1):

What does it say if you try this?

```
if (typeof window.XMLHttpRequest === 'function') 
     alert ('ok');
else
     alert ('not ok');
```

if it says "not ok" then try this code

```
if (typeof window.XMLHttpRequest === 'function') 
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
else
   var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
```

Comment: You might want to explain why you are asking to try this.

Comment: It says 'not ok'.  That was quite an astute response.  Going further from here, I see that I need to take Yurih Galanter's suggestion that is the first comment to my question.  It is also described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363212/window-xmlhttprequest-is-undefined-in-ie7-ie8

Comment: Provide more details in your Answers so that the readers will understand the underlying reason for your response.

Comment: In fairness to @Vash, he doesn't have enough rep points yet to post a comment, otherwise he probably would have asked this in a comment. Now he just needs to update the answer with the additional info Michael provided so it's more useful to others who discover this page in the future...currently it's not really an "answer".

Comment: sorry, first answer here on stackoverflow. Fixed